# How to slide down a logo from outside the screen?

Tags: android, imageview, android-animation

I'm trying to do a splashscreen where a logo appears from the top of the screen, and stop at the center of the screen.

I am using XML in my anim file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true">

    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:toYDelta="75%p"
        android:duration="3000" />
</set>
```

And this method to load the movement:

```
Animation fadein = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.fadein);
background.startAnimation(fadein);
background.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);

// load the animation
Animation animMoveDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.movedown);

// set animation listener
animMoveDown.setAnimationListener(this);
overlay.startAnimation(animMoveDown);
```

How I can put the logo above the screen and have it slide down to the center? Is it possible?

Comment: With minus `Ydelta` what is result?

Comment: Right!! this is the answer. Thank you.

Comment: YW, please accept my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all, in my case the XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true">

    <translate
        **android:fromYDelta="-50%p"**
        android:toYDelta="75%p"
        android:duration="3000" />
</set>
```

Comment: You're better off accepting an answer to show that it worked for whoever comes along next!

Answer (score 1):

It is absolutely possible! You'll have to play around with this a bit, but you'll basically just want to start at a negative YDelta

Here's what I used in my app, where I needed the very bottom of the image to start on the screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="-84%"
        android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

You're going to want to start at -100% and end at 50%, I think, so try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="-100%"
        android:toYDelta="50%"
        android:duration="3000" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as simple define `android:fromYDelta` with negative value.

Answer (score 0):

```
private fun buildSlideDownAndScaleAnimation(view: View): AnimationSet {
    val animSet = AnimationSet(true)
    animSet.fillAfter = false
    val duration: Long = 1000
    animSet.duration = duration
    animSet.interpolator = AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()

    val translate = TranslateAnimation(0f, 0f, -1000f, 0f)
    animSet.addAnimation(translate)

    val scale = ScaleAnimation(0f,
                               1f,
                               0f,
                               1f,
                               ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                               .5f,
                               ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                               .5f)

    animSet.addAnimation(scale)

    val alphaAnimation = AlphaAnimation(0f, 1f)
    alphaAnimation.startOffset = duration / 3
    animSet.addAnimation(alphaAnimation)

    return animSet
}
```